# Google maps api get list of all addresses from 2 coordinates

Tags: java, google-maps

I want to know the list of all addresses from a path, like the GPS does. For example, given 2 points (source and destination) in a map, what are the addresses I will have to pass to get my destination?

Anyone knows how can I do that using google maps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [GeoCoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) class.

With Reverse GeoCoding you can specify a max result set (here 1) for valid coordinates (lat, lng).

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I solved my problem with Google Directions API. Based on origin and destination, it gives some instructions (with the addresses), that is what I was looking for.